# Deformations of tensor categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, monoidal-categories, deformation-theory

What is meant by deformations of tensor categories? Why should one be interested in them, what can you do with them and where can I find a nice introduction to this concept? Furthermore what is the link with cohomology?

Intuitive explanations are very welcome.

Comment: Are you familiar with the original deformation theory of rings and algebras by Gerstenhaber and its relation with Hoschild cohomology? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: Not really, I only encountered deformations in the sense of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}(2))$ being a one-parameter deformation of $U(\mathfrak{sl}(2))$. I guess this fits in the framework of Gerstenhaber, but I never encountered a nice general definition of deformations. But I'll start there, maybe it will become clear what it is.

Comment: @AlexProvost: Is the text 'On the deformations of rings and algebras' a good place to start? Or are there other recommended texts?

Comment: Yes, that is the classic article on the subject. It's the one I read when I started learning about this, too. (The original Hoschild 1945 paper is also very good to go along with it.)

Comment: @AlexProvost: Alright, I'll read these articles first. Thank you.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/szendroi/defth.pdf) "The unbearable lightness of deformation theory" is also nice for working out explicit examples.